# How to find out the value of column1 a JSON string?

Tags: c#, json

please help me to find out the value of column1 from this JSON string:

```
{"company":{"oltpid":{"Column1":"345353"}}}
```

...using C#.net.  i tried with the following code. but didn't get the value of column1:

```
RootObject result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(JsonString);

public class RootObject
{
    public company[] companys;
    public class company
    {
        public oltpid[] oltp_id;
        public class oltpid
        {
            public String Column1;
        };   
    };
}
```

Comment: What value of result does debugger show?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have arrays in your json object, so you should not use them in your objects as well. You also need to use properties instead of variables, as JSON serializer works with properties. Try the following structure:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public company company { get; set; }
}

public class company
{
    public oltpid oltpid { get; set; }
}

public class oltpid
{
    public String Column1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get to the value of `Column1` by using this code:

```
RootObject result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(JsonString);
var yourValue = result.company.oltpid.Column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I give you a working solution with json.net

To install json.net from NuGet

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

and here's the code

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Company company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public Oltpid oltpid { get; set; }
}

public class Oltpid
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }  
}

var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var result = obj.company.oltpid.Column1
```